# Comments Toward/About

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, word-meaning

I have some question about the usage of the preposition "*toward*" [here](http://www.nytimes.com/2001/12/01/world/a-nation-challenged-diplomacy-us-to-press-iraq-to-let-un-search-for-banned-arms.html):

> The remarks from the senior officials were part of what has been a steady drumbeat of bellicose ***comments toward*** Iraq this week, including remarks by Mr. Bush that have cheered many conservatives and worried some European and Arab allies.

How is "*comments* ***toward***" somebody different from "*comments* ***about***" somebody?

Comment: I agree that **comments toward** sounds odd.  **comments aimed at** might be more idiomatic (in AmE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author's intention in your particular context is to use the first [definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/toward) from the American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language:

> In the direction of

In other words those comments were oriented toward Iraq or aimed (targeted) Iraq.

As for the use of **about**, according to the [definition #4](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/about) from the American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language:

> a. In reference to; relating to; concerned with: a book about snakes.

would imply that those comments were made relating to Iraq, or concerning Iraq.

Comment: I still don't see the difference between "*comments toward*" and "*comment about*".  You definitions suggest that "*toward*" is a cute rephrasing of "*about*".

Comment: @meatie, No, not at all. *In the direction of* is not the same as *relating to*.

Comment: But in the example sentence in the original question, would I get away with replacing "*toward*" with "*about*"?

Comment: @meatie, the example sentence reflects the author's intention.

Answer (score 1):

*Comments about X* would imply comments were not available in a medium where X could read/hear them.  The entity making the comments is not trying to say anything to X.

*Comments toward X* implies that X can hear/read the comments, and the entity making the comments is using the medium where comments are stored or communicated as an indirect method of delivering a message to X.

Comment: So, "*toward*" means the comments were made in the presence of the recipient?

Comment: Not necessarily, for example, you can make a comment toward someone in an online forum or social network, which they may not physically read until later.  *Comments about X* are not necessarily intended to be known by X, where as a *comment toward X* is.

Comment: I still don't see the difference between "*comments toward*" and "*comment about*".  It seems that "*toward*" is a cute rephrasing of "*about*".

Comment: It is in a way - when people make comments toward someone, as opposed to comments *to* someone, they are usually trying to avoid being direct for a reason such as politeness, passive-agressiveness, shyness, fear, political allegiances, etc.  You could utter a comment toward X, with that comment not being about X.  Such as your mother in law talking about you to her daughter - while you are in the room.